# Grouping Nodes with Radio Button

Tags: d3.js, force-layout

I have been trying to piece together an answer to this question but I am officially stumped.  I am working on a forced layout visualization in D3, very similar to http://vallandingham.me/vis/gates/.  The problem that I am having is getting my nodes to group and ungroup when I click a radio button.  The nodes will shift briefly to their new location but snap back to their original form almost immediately.  Any help with this matter would greatly appreciated!  I have literally spent hours scouring Jim's blog / code, and other examples form Bostock but to no avail. Below is my code.  Again, I'd appreciate any advice...

Thanks

```
<body>
 <form>
    <input type="radio" name="radio" value="P1",  checked="checked"> Group
    <input type="radio" name="radio" value="P2",  unchecked> Category Group
</form>
<script src="d3.v3.js"></script>
<script>

  var width = 960,
      height = 700;

  var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
       .attr("width", width)
       .attr("height", height) 

//Load Data
  d3.csv("data/ski5.csv", function(error, data) {

  var rScale = d3.scale.linear()
      .domain([0,d3.max(data, function (d) {return d.acres; })])
      .range([0, 12]);          

  var force = d3.layout.force()
      .nodes(data)
      .size([width, height])
      .on("tick", tick)
      .charge(charge);
    force.alpha()
    force.gravity(.45)
    force.start()

   var node = svg.selectAll("circle")
       .data(force.nodes()) 
       .enter()
       .append("circle")
       .attr("class", "node")
       .attr("r",  function(d) {return (rScale(d.acres));})
       .attr("stroke", "white")
       .attr("stroke-width", .5)
       .attr("fill", function(d) {return d.color;})
       .call(force.drag);
    svg.style("opacity", 1e-6)
       .transition()
       .duration(1300)
       .style("opacity", 1);

 function charge(d) {
     return ((rScale(d.acres)) * (rScale(d.acres)) * (-.65));
 } 


 function tick(e) {
    node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
  }


//Radio Button for Category Group
  d3.selectAll("input[value=P2]")
      .on("change", groupCategory);  

 function groupCategory() {
    data.forEach(function(d, i) {   
       d.x = d.x + (d.line*10 - d.x) * (.01 + 0.02);
       d.y = d.y + (300 - d.y) * (.01 + 0.02);
       });
   force.start();
 }

;}) 

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

i think you need to actually set the attributes of the nodes to the new positions. right now you are moving the position without changing any attributes, which might explain the behavior you are observing. in the example cited, the following happens:

```
.attr("cx", (d) -> d.x)
.attr("cy", (d) -> d.y)
```

with the new "cx" and "cy" being set by the method "move_towards_year". so you should create a  corresponding method in which you would place the logic you have already written:

```
d.x = d.x + (d.line*10 - d.x) * (.01 + 0.02);
d.y = d.y + (300 - d.y) * (.01 + 0.02);
```

then call this method in a manor similar to the "display_by_year" method:

```
display_by_whatever: () =>
  @force.gravity(@layout_gravity)
    .charge(this.charge)
    .friction(0.9)
    .on "tick", (e) =>
      @circles.each(this.your_move_method(e.alpha))
        .attr("cx", (d) -> d.x)
        .attr("cy", (d) -> d.y)
  @force.start()
```

to handle the radio button event (per your comment) do something like:

```
d3.select('radio button id/class').on('change', display_by_whatever)
```

Comment: As a follow up; in your example where would you put the radio event?  I am having difficulty adding that functionality in....Thanks!